# How to pass React context in tests for Higher Order Components using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a Button Component that's render with styles `(withStyles())`

The problem is that `withStyles` needs to have access to a theme.

This is an attempt at writing the mounting functions.

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import {
  withStyles,
  createGenerateClassName,
  createMuiTheme,
  jssPreset,
  MuiThemeProvider,
  getMuiTheme
} from 'material-ui/styles';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import globalThem from 'client/theme/base';

const theme = createMuiTheme(globalThem);
const { muiThemeProviderOptions } = (new MuiThemeProvider({ theme }, {})).getChildContext()

export const shallowWithStyles = node => shallow(
  node,
  {
    context: { muiThemeProviderOptions },
  }
)

export const mountWithStyles = node => mount(
  node,
  {
    context: { muiThemeProviderOptions },
  }
)
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem?

Comment: The theme object passed to withStyles is undefined meaning none of the theme styles are accessible..

Comment: have you tried to use `MuiThemeProvider` like in your app  `shallowWithStyles = Node => shallow(<MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={theme}><Node/></MuiThemeProvider>)`